# SendGrid integration with Keen IO

Tags: sendgrid, keen-io

Is it possible to send the SendGrid Transactional Template ID to Keen IO from SendGrid?  I want to filter on this field in Keen IO but I don't see that it is available.  When I reviewed the recent events in Keen IO it wasn't there either.

Answer (score 1):

In Keen IO you can see any property that was sent via web-hook. In order to see Transactional Template ID you need to configure SendGrid to send this additional custom argument. Please see SendGrid [docs regarding Unique Arguments](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Webhooks/event.html#-Unique-Arguments) for detailed information. 
Let us know if you need an further assistance.